# Some Serious SQL Query Optimization Needed (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, refactoring

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT IFNULL(sum(open_for), 0) total, count(IF(open_for > 0, 1, null)) wins, count(IF(open_for < 0, 1, null)) losses FROM `sport_points` WHERE (sportable_id = 1 and sportable_type = 'Team' and game_time > '2010-07-13 11:39:58 UTC'
```

It basically returns this aggregated data:

TEAM A

- open_for
- total: 2000
- wins: 20
- losses: 12

Now, imagine there are about 6 other columns in the table that I need execute separate queries to get all the column-specific aggregate data for one team.  For example:

```
SELECT IFNULL(sum(FINAL_FOR), 0) total, count(IF(open_for > 0, 1, null)) wins, count(IF(open_for < 0, 1, null)) losses FROM `sport_points` WHERE (sportable_id = 1 and sportable_type = 'Team' and game_time > '2010-07-13 11:39:58 UTC'
```

TEAM A

- final_for
- total: 4000
- wins: 40
- losses: 18

The problem with this approach is that I have to run about 6 separate queries for all the columns on well over 200 teams. It's a serious load problem.

Ideally, the query would return all the column-specific aggregate data for one team -- in one query.  It would look like this in the result:

TEAM A

- open_for_total
- open_for_wins
- open_for_losses
- final_for_total
- final_for_wins
- final_for_losses

...etc...

Comment: 6 separate queries I can understand, but it seems like these queries can be grouped by team id so you get the results of all 200 teams in the 6 different queries. 6 queries shouldn't present a load issue with 200 teams. Have you indexed your tables properly?

Comment: that approach might work...however, i don't always want all 200 teams at once...regardless, it may be an option...what would the sql look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the benefit of those who want to help:

Query 1:

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(sum(open_for), 0) total
    ,COUNT(IF(open_for > 0, 1, null)) wins
    ,COUNT(IF(open_for < 0, 1, null)) losses
FROM
    `sport_points`
WHERE
    sportable_id = 1
    AND sportable_type = 'Team'
    AND game_time > '2010-07-13 11:39:58 UTC'
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(SUM(FINAL_FOR), 0) total
    ,COUNT(IF(open_for > 0, 1, null)) wins
    ,COUNT(IF(open_for < 0, 1, null)) losses
FROM
    `sport_points`
WHERE 
    sportable_id = 1
    AND sportable_type = 'Team'
    AND game_time > '2010-07-13 11:39:58 UTC'
```

Desired output columns: teamname, typeofquery, value

Where typeofquery is one of:

- open_for_total
- open_for_wins
- open_for_losses
- final_for_total
- final_for_wins
- final_for_losses

derived from the two columns `open_for` and `final_for` in conjunction with the `wins` and `losses` columns.

Initially thinking about the problem I'm guessing an intermediate table might help processed with a `GROUP BY` clause.

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO
  temptable
SELECT
  teamname
  ,'open_for' type
  ,IFNULL(SUM(open_for), 0) total
  ,COUNT(IF(open_for > 0, 1, null)) wins
  ,COUNT(IF(open_for < 0, 1, null)) losses
FROM
  `sport_points`
WHERE
  sportable_id = 1
  AND sportable_type = 'Team'
  AND game_time > '...'
GROUP BY
  teamname
```

then run the same query but summing `final_for`. Now your temp table contains rows like:

```
teamname, type, total, wins, losses
TEAM A, open_for, 100, 37, 63
TEAM A, final_for, 30, 10, 20
TEAM B, open_for, 12, 8, 4
TEAM B, final_for, 50, 49, 1
```

Your final query could just concatenate the columns as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this as a single query which returns separate *columns* for each of the statistics. I'd then restructure the results in my application code if necessary. The query looks something like:

```
select teamname,
 sum(open_for) as open_total,
 count(if(open_for > 0, 1, null)) as open_wins,
 count(if(open_for < 0, 1, null)) as open_losses,
 sum(final_for) as final_total,
 count(if(final_for > 0, 1, null)) as final_wins,
 count(if(final_for < 0, 1, null)) as final_losses,
from sport_points
where sportable_id = 1
 and sportable_type = 'Team'
 and game_time > '...'
group by teamname
```

This, i suggest, is a more orthodox relational approach, and so one which is easily expressed in SQL. If it's not quite what you need in your application, then the place to make the adjustment is in code, which is far more flexible than SQL.

Comment: You can easily restrict this to a subset of teams (or even rows, whatever those correspond to) if you like - you just add conditions to the where clause as usual.